# Wordpress : load_textdomain won't load my .mo file (not for a theme nor a plugin but for a template part)

Tags: wordpress, translation

I am using Yoast's method to build an html site map in my Wordpress site. But it needs to be translated.

It uses a page template page-sitemap.php that uses a template part

```
<?php get_template_part('/partials/sitemap');  ?>
```

In this template part i ...

```
load_textdomain( 'site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages' );
```

The function returns a false. (" If .mo file is not readable or the import fails - returns false. Otherwise returns true. ")

The path is right for I list the files of the folder TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages' and it shows my language files.

As you see my domain name is 'site-map'. My .mo file is site-map-fr_FR.mo
Why can't it be loaded ?

Thanks for any clue,
nicolas

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer :
    load_textdomain( 'site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages' );
... gives the path of the folder containing the .mo file. but the path of every individual mo file should be used in its own oad_textdomain instruction :

```
load_textdomain('site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages/site-map-fr_FR.mo'); 
load_textdomain('site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages/site-map-en_US.mo'); 
load_textdomain('site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages/site-map-es_ES.mo'); 
load_textdomain('site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages/site-map-ru_RU.mo'); 
load_textdomain('site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages/site-map-de_DE.mo');
```

Shame on me it is a very obvious and useless thread ...
Sorry !

Comment: Feel no shame, be sure that you paved the way to many lost souls after you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `load_theme_textdomain('site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages');` instead your function.

Comment: Thanks but it has no effect. I thought that load_theme_textdomain was used for theme translation only. But it is true that these files are in my theme folder ...

Comment: @OneMinutePlease sorry for silly question, but did you change WPLANG constant in wp-config.php ?

Comment: Well Valery, it's not that silly :) ... i am using WPML plugin so the language status is handled by the plugin. Anyway the load_textdomain function returns a false which means that the mo file is not loaded. This is the root of the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Based on **OneMinutePlease** 's comment

With a simple modification, the function can be automated

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'jawda_theme_setup');
function jawda_theme_setup(){

  $directory = ROOT_DIR . 'languages/';

  if(is_dir($directory)) {

    $scan = preg_grep('~.*\.mo$~', scandir($directory));

    foreach($scan as $file) {

      if( file_exists($directory . $file) ){
        load_textdomain('JaWdA', $directory . $file);
      }
      
    }

  }

}
```